# Integral Calculation Problems-Something with square roots

Tags: calculus

Can someone please  help me calculate the following?

$ \int \frac{1+\sqrt{x} }{ \sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x^2 } } dx $

thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 3):

We can express our integral as 
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

The second integral is easy. The first, after the substitution $u=\sqrt{x}$, turns into a constant times $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}$.

This is a well-known *elliptic integral*, and cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 2):

I will consider the part $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$ only (The other part is easy). Make the substitution $x=\sin(u)$, we get:
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(u)}\sqrt{1-\sin^2(u)}}\cos(u)du=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(u)}}du$$

I believe the last integral is non-elementary.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the terms in the numerator.  The one with $1$ is a mess, according to [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%201/sqrt%28x%29/sqrt%281-x%5E2%29%20).  The one with $\sqrt x$ becomes $\int \frac 1{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx = \arcsin x$